# Why can't we implicitly convert a noconst-elements array to a full-const-elements array?

Tags: c++

Here is an example of what I mean (I am using VS 2022 with C++11):

```
// Printing function: does not modify any array member, so everything should be const
void PrintArray(int const*const (&ct)[3]) 
{
    printf("ct: x%p, {%u, %u, %u}\n", 
           &ct, ct[0] ? *ct[0] : 0, ct[1] ? *ct[1] : 0, ct[2] ? *ct[2] : 0);
}
```

```
int main(int argc, unsigned short* argv[])
{
    // At some point: declare (and use) a modifiable array
    int a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;
    int* t[3] = {&a, &b, &c};

    // At some later point: want to use the array without modifying it,
    // then lets try some conversions
    int* (&u)[3] = t;           // OK - Same type conversion
    int*const (&v)[3] = t;      // OK - adding first constness on array elements
    int const*const (&w)[3] = t;    // FAIL: adding both constnesses on elements: 
                        // error C2440 "cannot convert from 'int *[3]' to 
                                        //'const int *const (&)[3]"  (ON VS 2022 C++ 11)
    int const*const (&x)[3] = const_cast<int const*const(&)[3]>(t); 
                                        // FAIL: same error C2440
    int const*const (&y)[3] = reinterpret_cast<int const*const(&)[3]>(t); 
                                        // OK - but annoyingly verbose and source of casting
                                        // errors

    // Of course the same problem happens for passing through functions call
    PrintArray(t);                      // FAIL
    PrintArray(reinterpret_cast<int const*const(&)[3]>(t));     // OK... but still annoying !

    return 0;
}
```

OK, we know that reinterpret_cast is working, so I have a workaround here. So my question is more theoritical about C++ language:

- Does someone know if the implicit conversion compiles on other compilers, like gcc ?
- Does someone know if the C++ standard forbid this failing implicit conversion ?
- And mostly, if the standard does forbid it, WHY ??? I KNOW that const conversions can lead to const/unconst inconsistencies sometimes. E.g. would have been the case if converting `t` to `int const* (&)[3]` because we could have added a const int into an array that is not const at the begining. But, in my example above, everything is const so I cannot find any weakness. Does someone see one ? Or is it just because it was too complex at the time for compilers to assert the rightness of the conversion ?
- (Additional question for the braves: why cons_cast is failing here while it is only a constness casting ?)

These questions are for my C++ culture, I am open to all your analysis :)
Kind regards to everybody.

Comment: Cannot reproduce with other compilers.

Comment: @n.m. Very interesting, thank you very much for the test. Which ones did you use ?

Comment: gcc and clang on godbolt.